# Pytorch LSTM - How do I implement it without using a for loop?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, lstm

I implemented this very simple LSTM model:

```
class LSTM_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers, rnn_size, vf_h, vf_w, batch_size, num_steps, minval, maxval):
        super(LSTM_Model, self).__init__()
        self.num_steps = num_steps
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.rnn_size = rnn_size
        self.vf_h = vf_h
        self.vf_w = vf_w
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, padding_idx = 0) #12112->1000
        self.embed.weight.data.uniform_(minval, maxval)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True) 

    def get_first_nonpad_index(self,words):
        i = 0
        encoded_word_list = words.view(-1).tolist()
        for word in encoded_word_list:
          if word == 0:
            i+=1
          else:
            break
        return i

    def forward(self, words, hidden_state):
        first_nonpad_index = self.get_first_nonpad_index(words)                                       
        number_of_words = 20 - first_nonpad_index                                                     
        sentence_no_padding = torch.narrow(words, 2, first_nonpad_index, number_of_words).to(device)  
        embedded_seq = self.embed(sentence_no_padding)
        state = hidden_state
        for n in range(number_of_words):
            w_emb = embedded_seq[:, :, n]            
            rnn_output, state = self.lstm(w_emb, state) 

        lang_feat = rnn_output.view(self.batch_size, 1, 1, self.rnn_size)         #shape:(1, 1, 1000) -> (1, 1, 1, 1000)
        lang_feat = f.normalize(lang_feat, p=2, dim=3)                            #shape=(1, 1, 1, 1000)

        lang_feat = lang_feat.repeat(1, self.vf_h, self.vf_w, 1)                  #shape=(1, 40, 40, 1000)
        return lang_feat
```

I wish to reimplement the same model without using a for loop in the forward function. I wrote this new forward function:

```
    def forward(self, words, state):
        first_nonpad_index = self.get_first_nonpad_index(words)                                       
        number_of_words = 20 - first_nonpad_index                                                     
        sentence_no_padding = torch.narrow(words, 2, first_nonpad_index, number_of_words).to(device)  
        

        embedded_seq = [self.embed(sentence_no_padding[:, :, n]) for n in range(number_of_words)]

        embedded_seq = torch.cat(embedded_seq).view(1, number_of_words, -1)

        rnn_output, state = self.lstm(embedded_seq, state) 
        last_output = rnn_output[:, -1, :]




        lang_feat = last_output.view(self.batch_size, 1, 1, self.rnn_size)         #shape=(1, 1, 1, 1000)
        lang_feat = f.normalize(lang_feat, p=2, dim=3)                            #shape=(1, 1, 1, 1000) 
        lang_feat = lang_feat.repeat(1, self.vf_h, self.vf_w, 1)                  #shape=(1, 40, 40, 1000)

        return lang_feat
```

However, when I use the new forward function I am getting different results than before. Can you please spot what did I do wrong? I obviously want the 2nd implementation to be equivalent to the first one

Answer (score 0):

You implemented `nn.LSTM` correctly in the second example. But I dont think the first one is correct because you iterate over your sequence and then also apply `nn.LSTM` but `nn.LSTM` itself iterates over your sequence in the background. If you want to implement an LSTM yourself in Pytorch without using `nn.LSTM` you should probably use `nn.LSTMCell`. If you then want to check if both both methods give the exact same results you would have to make sure that your weights are the same/deterministic.
And a last thing: Dont pass `state` to your `forward` function, just initialize it every iteration in the function itself using something like

```py
hidden = (torch.zeros(layers, x.size(0), hidden_size).to(device=device), torch.zeros(layers, x.size(0), hidden_size).to(device=device))
```

Every forward pass the hidden state should be reinitialized with zeros.

Comment: In all RNN-like layers state is __by default__ initialized with zeros, no need to "reinitialize it" explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have 2 questions:
1. I used the following tutorial from pytorch's official website:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html
as you can see they use lstm (and not LSTMCell) for their "quick example". How is this different?

2. I'll check to see if there's an equivalence after switching to LSTMCell. However, LSTMCell doesn't have a batch_first attribute, is there a way to fix this with minimal changes?

Thanks again.

Comment: If it helps, in both cases num_layers = 1

Comment: I think LSTMCell doesnt take a sequence as input but only a sequence element instead (ive never used it myself)

Comment: What about question 1? One of their 2 official proposed implementations uses a loop with an LSTM (rather than LSTMCell)